# Number of FP64 CUDA cores in GTX 1070

Tags: cuda, gpu, hardware

I have found information about how much does Tesla P100 contain CUDA cores per one SM. Its 64*FP32 and 32*FP64. I am unable to find any numbers for GTX 1070.

Also followup question. Since ratio of cores for Tesla is 1:2 does it mean that double precision performance is at max one half of performance of single precision kernel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have found information about how much does Tesla P100 contain CUDA cores per one SM. Its 64*FP32 and 32*FP64. I am unable to find any numbers for GTX 1070.

GTX 1070 is a cc6.1 GPU.  We can refer to [this table](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions__throughput-native-arithmetic-instructions) in the programming guide to discover relative instruction throughput:

```
                                                    6.1

32-bit floating-point add, multiply, multiply-add   128
64-bit floating-point add, multiply, multiply-add   4
```

These numbers are *per-clock* and *per-SM*.  It means that there are 128 FP32 floating-point units, and 4 FP64 floating point units per SM.  You then only need to multiply those numbers by the number of SMs in your cc6.1 GPU (which you can obtain with `deviceQuery`for example), to get the total FP32 and the total FP64 cores in the GPU.

> Also followup question. Since ratio of cores for Tesla is 1:2 does it mean that double precision performance is at max one half of performance of single precision kernel?

Yes, that is what it means (for suitably measured compute-bound codes, i.e. codes where the limiter in each case is this particular metric).  Note that this 1:2 ratio does not apply to all Tesla processors, but it is applicable to Fermi Tesla processors (e.g. M2070, M2090, etc.) and it is applicable to Tesla P100.  Perhaps a better way to state it would be that for GPUs of this type, the 1:2 ratio reflects the ratio of *peak theoretical performance* for FP64:FP32 comparison.